# Positioning toast in Android?

Tags: android, toast

I'm new to Android. Now I'm learning about Toast. Is it possible to position a toast?

Whenever I toast, it is coming in bottom of the screen.

Here is my code:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setGravity(int, int, int)` method.

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

`Toast` Documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

`Gravity` Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this [example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-custom-toast-example) to position and customize toast in android

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 200);
toast.show();
```